# Can "没完没了" be used as an Adjective/形容词？What are some adjective to express describe someone that is "没完没了" or someone what won't stop?

Tags: phrase, idioms, adjectives, equivalent-phrase

I am wondering if there is a adjective that is similar to **没完没了**, to describe someone that is won't stop at something.
An example would be someone what offended you but still won't stop making jokes.

Can I use **没完没了** to describe someone like this or are any words that is more accurate?

Example would be: “他**没完没了**的。人家都生气了他还在开玩笑。” Can I replace ***没完没了*** with something else?
If **没完没了** cannot be used as an adjective, what are some adjectives that could be used in its stead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 没完没了的 is an adjective that describes an action or event. It is not suitable for describing person's behavior

Example:

没完没了的審訊 - Endless interrogations

没完没了的任務 - Endless missions

> 没完没了地(endlessly; persistently) is an adverb that describes verbs like "talk", "complain", or "debate". All related to human behavior

Example:

没完没了地追問 - kept asking questions

没完没了地投訴 - complains endlessly

> To describe a person who often engages in such behavior, you could use 纏人的 (pestering), or 煩人的 (annoying) to describe him

Example:

他没完没了地追問，真是纏人的傢伙 - He kept asking questions, he was really a pestering guy.

他没完没了地投訴，真是煩人的傢伙 - He complains endlessly, what an annoying guy

> Adjectives similar to 没完没了的:

無窮無盡的 (with no end/ endless)

無休無止的 (nonstop/ endless)